# TypeError: oldMember.roles.every is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, typeerror

```
client.on("guildMemberUpdate", function (guild, oldMember, newMember) {
  //declare changes
  var Changes = {
    unknown: 0,
    addedRole: 1,
    removedRole: 2,
    username: 3,
    nickname: 4,
    avatar: 5,
  };
  var change = Changes.unknown;

  //check if roles were removed
  var removedRole = "";
  oldMember.roles.every(function (value) {
    if (newMember.roles.cache.find("id", value.id) == null) {
      change = Changes.removedRole;
      removedRole = value.name;
    }
  });
```

I am trying to make a bot tracking add / remove roles from a user. But every time I enable and change the user's role, I get this error. If anyone knows what the problem is, please help.

Discord.js: **v12.3.1**

npm: **v6.14.8**

Comment: First thing to figure out is what `oldMember.roles` actually is.

Comment: Also–it doesn't seem like `Array#every` is a good choice here. You're not checking that every element satisifies a certain condition, you're just iterating through it and finding a certain role. Perhaps you want to use `Array#find` or `Array#filter`?

Comment: Discord.js: **v12.3.1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few errors with deprecated functions. First of all, `newMember.roles` returns a `Manager`, so you will have to go an extra step and pass it through the `cache` property.

Also, `find("id", "<id>")` is deprecated, instead use `find(role => role.id === '<id>')`.

Lastly, as pointed out in the comments, `.every()` doesn't seem like the function you're looking for.

```js
// iterate a function through every role the user used to have
oldMember.roles.cache.forEach((value) => {
 if (!newMember.roles.cache.find((role) => role.id === value.id)) {
  change = Changes.removedRole;
  removedRole = value.name;
 }
});
```

Comment: Another thing I forgot to mention is you can replace `find(role => role.id === '<id>')` with the much simpler `get('<id>')`

Answer (score 0):

Roles isn't an array like it should be, it's an object instead.  Ensure your server call is returning what you think it should.